# Cohomology ring of $S^3 \setminus A $ and $S^3 \setminus B $,where $A$ is union of two once linked circle and $B$ is union of two unlinked circles

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $A$ is union of two once linked circles in $S^3 $ and $B $ is union of two unlinked circles.show that $S^3 \setminus A $ and $S^3 \setminus B$ have same cohomology group but not same cohomology ring.

I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Can you compute the cohomology as a group or the homology or something?

Comment: Do you know Alexander duality?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality

Comment: @Alvarez..
No..actually I can't understand that how these spaces looks like. I mean what is the deformation retraction of these slaces....

Comment: @johnson

Sorry,I don't know Alexander duality.....

Comment: If you do a stereographic projection from INoneE of the points in one of tour two circles, what do you get?

Comment: @alvarez..
INoneE means?

Comment: @Sudipta Biswas You can compute the cohomolgy with a Mayer-Vietoris sequence on S3∖C1 and S3∖C2 where C1 and C2 are the two circles. S3∖Ci can also be computed from a Mayer-Vietoris sequence. The cohomology rings in dimension 1 can be computed from the wedge product of two 1 forms. Each form integrates to the linking number of closed loops with one of the circles. The wedge product can be integrated over a torus inside a tubular neighborhood of one of the circles. Fubini's theorem reduces the integral to a product of linking numbers.

Comment: This exercise is the last one in part 5 of Munkres' *Elements of Algebraic Topology*. Alexander duality, Poincaré duality, linking numbers and de Rham cohomology have not yet been introduced at that point in the book. Perhaps the OP is asking for a solution that uses none of those tools, i.e a method for triangulating those spaces and making it visible that the cohomology rings are not isomorphic.